# How to add component to a test case using API?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I created a test case using tcms_api

```
test_case = rpc_client.TestCase.create({
    'summary': 'My testing',
    'product': 2,
    'category': 2,
    'priority': 1,
    'is_automated': True,
    'text': 'my first test case',
    'case_status': 2,  # CONFIRMED
})
```

I wanted to add component to the test case, but could not find a sample or the syntax in API document. I tried the following with my guess and the update in change log:

```
rpc_client.TestCase.add_component(test_case['id'], [3, 6])
```

I got the error below. Can you please advise how to construct the query for component query? Thanks.

> xmlrpc.client.Fault:
>
> Fault -32603: 'Internal error: Component matching query does not exist.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.rpc.api.testcase.html#tcms.rpc.api.testcase.add_component) the signature of this method is:

```
function:: XML-RPC TestCase.add_component(case_id, component_id)
```

The docs tell you that `component_id` is an int, not a list.

^^^^ scratch that, the documentation is slightly wrong.

The second parameter is a string which should be the component name!

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate your help!